# mysql noop or null statement equivalent

Tags: mysql

When coding I personally like to complete my flow control/structure before filling it in. To allow it to work in oracle I could just put a null; command [oracle null command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/null_statement.htm#LNPLS01330) in the empty block to satisfy the parser. In mysql i'm getting an error for an empty codeblock and using null; doesn't work.

e.g.

```
if( _orgId IS NULL ) then
   select _orgId;

else
   null; -- this throws an error.
   -- TODO: Write complex statement.
end if;
```

Does Mysql have a null command equivalent and if so what is it?

Comment: Maybe `SELECT NULL` ?

Comment: @ITgoldman I did try that and it does work but results in an output that I don't want so I was hoping for something better when I asked. Sorry for not including that in the question.

Comment: BEGIN END syntax

Comment: That type of `IF` only works in stored procedures. You do have `IFNULL(...)` in MySQL.

Comment: Is the error you're receiving from MySQL? If yes, what is the error message?

Comment: @tadman How many SQL queries involve flow control???

Comment: It depends on your philosophy, but in practice you can get by with almost none. I prefer to keep most of that in the application layer. You can of course do the opposite and go deep down the stored procedures rabbit hole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL supports a statement `DO <expression>;`

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/do.html

It doesn't matter what the expression is, the statement does not return any results. The common use of this statement is for calling functions such as `RELEASE_LOCK()` or any other function that has a side-effect.

So you can use it as a no-op by writing any expression that has no side-effect:

```
DO NULL;
```